# Cannot set root directory of a web app in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7, spring-tool-suite

I have a spring mvc web project developing on STS 3.1, lets name it MYPROJECT.

When I run it on Apache Tomcat 7, I have to type "http://localhost:8080/MYPROJECT"
but I want it to run on the root "http://localhost:8080/"
how can I set the deployment path to "/" instead of "/MYPROJECT"?

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the Context Root.

1. Right click your project in Package Explorer
2. Select 'Properties'
3. Select 'Web Project Settings'
4. Enter '/' (without quotes).

Next time you open your project, load the URL `http://localhost:8080/`

Note that in STS 3.2 (Mac OS X 3.6.8) I find I have to reset this option from time to time as it unexpectedly reverts to the project name.